# Кривоватый текст (дата) в колонке "Предстоящие события"

Tags: дефект, локализация, выборы, даты

Как-то не совсем по-русски - "сен". Пришлось даже напрячь извилину, чтобы понять, что там написано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на enSO сокращение есть?

Comment: @dIm0n там сейчас нет такого блока.

Comment: Да, понимаю. Я к тому, что если на enSO тоже сокращение, то этот вопрос надо не сюда адресовать, т.е. "sep -> сен" нормальный перевод

Comment: А почему полностью не написать?

Comment: Вообще же я думаю, что лучше написать "8 сен.", чем "сен 8". Если полностью, то "8 сентября", а не "сентября 8". Благозвучнее, на мой взгляд

Comment: Завёл смежный [баг на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353547/339911) о датах под графиком репутации и сослался там на текущий.